# "Смотря, что делали родители всё это время", - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

> Для Инги: «В многодетной семье с внимательными родителями и детьми без
>   детского сада один вырос…» Так, извините, тут… А! «Один вырос аутистом,
>   другой безответственным, 18 и 17 лет. Вы…» Ой, господи. Нет, я не могу
>   прочитать. К сожалению, сообщение оборвано.
>
> И. ИЛЬМ: Думаю, речь шла о том, что в семье, где много детей, очень
>   разные дети. Но ведь многое зависит от родителей. **Смотря, что делали
>   родители всё это время.** Не только рожали, но, наверное, должны были
>   и заниматься своими ребятами. Да? И потом аутизм, насколько мне
>   известно, не продукт воспитания.

Comment: Строчка с запятой вдохновляет на другой контекст:
_Он бил баклуши, сидя у окна. 
Смотря, что делали родители 
Всё это время.
И мысль возникла у него одна:
Наследственно меня обидели -
Умру от лени!_

Comment: Змий коварррный! Всё одно - с размера ты сбился! )))

Comment: Это шестистишие с "треугольной" рифмой abcabc (с - укороченные строки, что случается в старофранцузском шестистишии) - так сказали учёные: http://www.timskorenko.ru/uchebnik3.html. В худшем случае я свободно и по-братски улучшил рифмой французскую старину, предварявшую наступление равенства для строк.

Comment: Ой, просвещённый ты какой!.. Если смыслишь в abcabc, может, ты ещё и смысл стихов воспримешь? У меня есть вопрос без ответа - я прошу просто пересказать сюжет! Забей, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, в поиск - ссылка не помещается: ***Можете ли Вы пересказать “сюжет” ахмадулинского стихотворения, наполненного архаизмами и церковнославянизмами?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна — это неразложимое сочетание. Грамота.ру пишет:

> СМОТРЯ ГДЕ / ... / ЧТО, неразложимое сочетание
>
> Между частями сочетания знак препинания не ставится.
>
> «Ну, это смотря кто с кем воюет», – сказал я. Ю. Домбровский, Хранитель древностей. О каждом выразительном лице был подобран текст из поэтов усадебного быта, из архивных материалов дома, но больше Алпатов сам сочинял всевозможное, смотря кто чем из гостей интересуется. М. Пришвин, Мирская чаша. «Хотите варенья?» – «Смотря какого».
>
> ! Не смешивать с сочетанием деепричастия «смотря» и союзного слова.
>
> Смотря, как он на охоте скакал всегда первый, не разбирая дороги, соседи говорили согласно, что из него никогда не выйдет путного столоначальника. А. Пушкин, Барышня-крестьянка. ...